# Design a shift register in VHDL

Tags: loops, vhdl, shift

I try to design a bch code as a shift register, so I have this schematic:

[image: BCH Code Shift Register]
*(clickable)*

And I made a VHDL code in Altera Quartus to design this shift register with loops, the compilation works but it doesn't make the expected result during the simulation in ModelSim (no output). It may have some errors in my code:

```
-- Library declaration
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_arith.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;


-- Entity declaration
ENTITY bchcode_implementation_top IS

PORT(clk : IN std_logic;                    
  Q : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));

END bchcode_implementation_top;


-- Architecture declaration
ARCHITECTURE arch_bchcode_implementation_top OF bchcode_implementation_top IS

SIGNAL M: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "10000000";

BEGIN
PROCESS(clk)

    VARIABLE W: std_logic;
   VARIABLE D: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";

        BEGIN
            loop_bchcode: FOR I IN 7 TO 0 LOOP
                IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
                    W := D(0) XOR M(I);
                    D(7) := W;
                    D(6) := D(7);
                    D(5) := D(6);
                    D(4) := D(5);
                    D(3) := D(4) XOR W;
                    D(2) := D(3);
                    D(1) := D(2) XOR W;
                    D(0) := D(1) XOR W;
                END IF;
            Q <= D;
        END LOOP loop_bchcode;
END PROCESS;

END arch_bchcode_implementation_top;
```

If someone have an idea please.. thank you for your reponse.

Comment: Variables are assigned immediately. For example if `D(6) := D(7)` and then `D(5) := D(6)` , `D(5)` will be equal to `D(7)`. It means the value of `D(6)` was destroyed and you must change the order of assignments. So if you want to use variables the order of assignment must be `D(0)`, `D(1)` , ..., `D(7)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed for all D but I still don't have the expected result, If someone can tell me if there are other errors in my code please, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, I think you want to design the following schematic :
[image]

As I mentioned in the above comment, if you want to use variables (instead of signals), you must change the order of assignments.

Also the range of loop must be `7 DOWNTO 0` (instead of `7 TO 0`).

The output is ready after 1 cycle. If you want to do the operation in 8 cycles, you must use a counter that is incremented on each clock rising edge. (instead of using `for loop`)

I edited your code with the above changes and simulated it with Modelsim 10.3. I could get the correct result on the first clock rising edge :

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Entity declaration
ENTITY bchcode_implementation_top IS
    PORT(
        clk : IN  std_logic;                    
        Q   : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END bchcode_implementation_top;


-- Architecture declaration
ARCHITECTURE arch_bchcode_implementation_top OF bchcode_implementation_top IS
    SIGNAL M : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0) := "10000000";
BEGIN

    PROCESS(clk)
        VARIABLE I : integer;
        VARIABLE W : std_logic;
        VARIABLE D : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0) := "00000000";
    BEGIN
        loop_bchcode: FOR I IN 7 DOWNTO 0 LOOP
            IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
                    W := D(0) XOR M(I);
                    D(0) := D(1) XOR W;
                    D(1) := D(2) XOR W;
                    D(2) := D(3);
                    D(3) := D(4) XOR W;
                    D(4) := D(5);
                    D(5) := D(6);
                    D(6) := D(7);
                    D(7) := W;
            END IF;
        END LOOP loop_bchcode;
        Q <= D;
    END PROCESS;

END arch_bchcode_implementation_top;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. When I compile on Quartus, I have few errors: "Can't infer register for D[5] because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge ". (also for D[6] and D[7])

Comment: And when I simulate the code, it work's but the results don't match with the results computed theoretically, given here http://www.noelshack.com/2015-18-1430179107-bchcode-crc-implementation.jpeg (D7 to D0)

Answer (score 0):

I finally fix the problem, here is my code to describe a shift register for bch code (15,7), thank you Amir for your help.

```
-- Library declaration
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;



-- Entity declaration
ENTITY bchcode_implementation_top IS

PORT(clk, rst : IN std_logic;
 Din : IN std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  Dout : BUFFER std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)); -- OUT port cannot be read back to the design

END bchcode_implementation_top;


-- Architecture declaration
ARCHITECTURE arch_bchcode_implementation_top OF bchcode_implementation_top  IS

SIGNAL count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

BEGIN
PROCESS(clk, rst, Din)

VARIABLE I : integer := 7;

BEGIN
    count <= Din;

        IF rst = '1' THEN
            Dout <= "00000000";
        ELSE
            IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
                Dout(0) <= Dout(1) XOR (Dout(0) XOR count(I));
                Dout(1) <= Dout(2) XOR (Dout(0) XOR count(I));  
                Dout(2) <= Dout(3);
                Dout(3) <= Dout(4) XOR (Dout(0) XOR count(I));
                Dout(4) <= Dout(5);
                Dout(5) <= Dout(6);
                Dout(6) <= Dout(7);
                Dout(7) <= Dout(0) XOR count(I);
                I := I - 1;
            END IF;
        END IF; 

END PROCESS;

END arch_bchcode_implementation_top;
```